# Non-trivial examples of selective coideals of $\omega$

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

$\newcommand{\H}{\mathcal{H}}$
$\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}$
Recall that a coideal $\H$ over $\omega$ is **selective** if for every $\{A_n : n < \omega\} \subseteq \H$, where $i < j \implies A_i \supseteq A_j$, there exists some $B \in \H$ such that $B/n := \{m \in B : m > n\} \subseteq A_n$ for all $n \in B$. There are two canonical examples of selective coideals, both of which can be constructed in $\mathsf{ZFC}$:

- The entire $[\omega]^\omega$ is of course a selective coideal.
- Let $\A$ be a mad (maximal almost disjoint) family of subsets of $\omega$. Let $\H$ be the set of all infinite subsets of $\omega$ which cannot be covered up to a finite set by finitely many members of $\A$. Then $\H$ is a selective coideal.

Are there any more examples of selective coideals that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can prove to exist? Note that I'm not looking for selective coideals that exist with further assumptions (e.g. under $\mathsf{CH}$, there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ many Ramsey ultrafilters, but I'm not asking for such examples).

Comment: @bof By definition $\mathcal{H}$ is a coideal if $\mathcal{I} := \mathcal{P}(\omega) \setminus \mathcal{H}$ is an ideal. This is not the same as a filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Section 12 in [S. Todorcevic, Topics in Topology, Lecture notes in Mathematics Vol. 1652, Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg 1997](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0096295)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).